# javascript service is not returning promise

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS application.  I have loginService.js file which defines login service as below:

```
(function () {

    var loginService = function ($http) {
        var login = function (userName, loginPassword) {

            var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + userName + "&password=" + loginPassword;

           $http.post("/Token", data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
                 .then(function (response) {
                     return response.data;
                 });


        };

        return {
            login: login
        };
    };

    var module = angular.module("MyApp");
    module.factory("loginService", loginService);
}());
```

and LoginController in javascript is defined as below:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("kanbanBoard");

    var LoginController = function ($scope, $location, loginService, localStorageService) {

        var loginData = {
            userName: "",
            loginPassword: ""
        };

        $scope.loginData = loginData;

        var onLoginComplete = function (data) {
            alert(data);
            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: userName });

            //$location.url("/");
        };

        var onError = function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $scope.error = result;
        }

        $scope.login = function () {

            loginService.login($scope.loginData.userName, $scope.loginData.loginPassword)
                          .then(onLoginComplete, onerror);
        }

    };

    app.controller("LoginController", LoginController);
}());
```

I am getting **Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference** in LoginController.js file.  As far my understanding loginService class should return promise which being handled in LoginController.  I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: How is dependency injection working here? You're registering `module.factory("loginService", accountManager);` (strange naming?) and injecting it unnamed into `LoginController`. Is `angular` able to find it without throwing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from $http.post by returning it in the login function:

```
      return $http.post("/Token", data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
             .then(function (response) {
                 return response.data;
             });
```

Otherwise void is returned and so (null).then() causes the error you mention.

Comment: the outer function login doesn't automatically return the return from the inner anonymous function...you can chain the promises...

Comment: This silly mistake I was doing.  It is working now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the value of `$http.post` in the call to `accountManager.login(...)`, so it will return `undefined`, which is certainly not a then-able.